# LINQ to JSON in .net 4.0 Client Profile

Tags: c#, json, .net-client-profile

How would I go about about using LINQ to JSON in the .net 4 Client Profile in C#. I'd like to query certain json responses as shown in [msdn blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2008/08/21/linq-to-json.aspx) without having to write out a contract (datacontract, servicecontract, etc). I really only need to query(read) the response, I don't need to modify the json response. (Also would a datacontract be faster than LINQ to JSON?)

Alternatively I could use XML or the full .net 4 framework, but I'm hoping that this can be avoided. I can use external libraries if it's better than installing the whole framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JSON.net](http://json.codeplex.com/) is quite popular and seems to be what you're after.

Comment: JSON.net's [SelectToken](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/SelectToken.html) did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

If your service is used by Ajax (jQuery) clients, you will get the best performance by using JSON.

Another recommendation; in order to get rid of the same domain policy, I recommend you to enable crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled functionality:

```
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="myHttpBinding" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
    </webHttpBinding>
```

Regarding the DataContract; in your scenario, a DataContract is not really needed.

Example code:

- Your Service:

  ```
  [ServiceContract]
  [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
  public class BlogService {

       [OperationContract]
       [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
       public List<Article> GetBlogArticles()
       {
           return Article.GetDummyArticles.ToList();
       }

  }
  ```
- Article Class (excerpt):

  ```
  public class Article    {

       public string Title { get; set; }
       public string Body { get; set; }

       public static IEnumerable<Article> GetDummyArticles() {
           yield return new Article { Title = "Article 1", Body = "sdlkfjsdlkfjskl" };
           yield return new Article { Title = "Article 2", Body = "sfsfsdfd23434wfdfsfdfkfjskl" };
       }
    }
  ```

For your scenario I actually can't find a reason to use any (3rd-party) library since WCF4 already contains native support for JSON with or without Padding.